# Is there a difference between life changing and life altering?

Tags: word-difference

Is there a difference between life changing and life altering?
I searched in a dictionary but it gives the same meaning .

Comment: Well, why would there be a difference if a dictionary says there isn't? Please [edit] to explain why you'd expect or look for a difference.

Comment: I don't look for a difference , I just see them in my book and wondered if is there a difference.^^

Comment: So why not quote the instances where you saw these examples, there *might* be a difference if the context forces it.

Comment: What @NathanTuggy asked is simply _Why do you think there should be any difference?_ If you are asking, it means you think there could be any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's very little difference in how they are used.  **But**, that being said, *to change* and *to alter* are synonymous but not the same.  "Change" is generic and can cover pretty much any kind of transformation.  "Alter" means to make small but significant changes to something, often to improve it in some way.

Consider the following sentences:

> How many times have you changed your clothes today?
>
> How many times have you altered your clothes today?

When you change your clothes, you put on new clothes.  When you *alter* your clothes, you take the ones you have and modify them (most commonly by tailoring).  The first sentence is routine.  The second sentence is odd, since you don't usually *alter* your clothing several times in one day.

So there's a small difference in *nuance* between life-changing and life-altering -- but I'm having a hard time thinking of an example that effectively illustrates this difference, so it might be a purely academic distinction.

Comment: The question is **Is there a difference between life changing and life altering?** and I think the answer is "no." What is the benefit to the OP of _So there's a small difference in nuance between life-changing and life-altering, but I'm having a hard time thinking of an example that effectively illustrates this difference._ ... ? How does this add to  our _"...library of detailed answers to every question about learning the English language."_ .. ?

Comment: I'm going to take a different stance; I think this answer explains the overlap and distinctions fairly well. I think _life-altering_ sounds a bit more dramatic than _life-changing_, though, for the most part, they can be used interchangeably in most contexts. It's kind of like the difference between *big* and *huge* – both words convey the same meaning, but to different degrees. One word seems more apt than the other for something extraordinarily big.